# Calling GetRequestStream() hangs WPF UI for 1sec

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a wpf application which has controls one label and two butons for start and stop timers.

I have created two DispatcherTimers one timer will fire after every 50 milliseconds and update the lable with count value. Another DispatcherTimer will fire after every 2 seconds it will Post data to a HTTP post test server called "http://posttestserver.com/post.php?dir=Test". In this timer i am using GetRequestStream which causes UI to stop 1 sec but my data is posting to posttestserver.
I have used the following code.

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

```
    static int count = 0;
    DispatcherTimer dispatchtimer = null;
    DispatcherTimer WebDispatchTimer = null;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dispatchtimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        WebDispatchTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        WebDispatchTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
        dispatchtimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
        dispatchtimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatchtimer_Tick);
        WebDispatchTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(senddata_Tick);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebDispatchTimer.Start();
        dispatchtimer.Start();
    }
    private void dispatchtimer_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        count += 1;
        label1.Content = count.ToString();
    }
    private void senddata_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        string postdata = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server\n";
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://posttestserver.com/post.php?dir=abcd");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postdata);
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            request.Proxy = null;
            using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                dataStream.Flush();
                dataStream.Close();
            }
            var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            response.Close();
            request.Abort();
            request = null;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            WebDispatchTimer.Stop();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            WebDispatchTimer.Stop();
        }         
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebDispatchTimer.Stop();
        dispatchtimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

I don't want my UI to hang for 1 sec. where i made a mistake ? Help me.

Comment: Assuming you've read the Manual for [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you know that it runs on UI thread... So I guess your expectation of not having UI frozen is where your mistake is - according to your code it should freeze UI while getting response as it runs on UI thread (unlike with regular `Timer`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now i have changed the webdispatcher timer to System.Timers.Timer WebDispatchTimer now every thing works fine.That solved my problem Thanks for your quick help.